# Extract data from SCAN_RESULTS ZXing

Tags: android, zxing

I have a new question this time with ZXing. O.K I have read all that I can find on this site about using ZXing with an app, but I am confused. I have written my DB app and I want to create a barcode with data, i.e Group name, Hours and cost, nothing complex. I can create the barcode online, not a prob. The problem is how to I extract the Group name, hours and cost from the "contents" returned by the SCAN_RESULTS in ZXing.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.scanButton:
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);
    break;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //barcode is variable where the string from SCAN_RESULT is stored
            String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
           // etName.setText(barcode);
```

Many thanks

Comment: that would depend on how you've encoded the data in your barcode, which you've neglected to post so there is really no way we can answer. Can you post an example of how you are encoding this data within the barcode using the online generator? Perhaps post a sample of a typical string that you are encoding.

Comment: Hi here is a simple example of how I generate the barcode. I use code-128 and a simple alpha numeric text, "FCE1 1.5 22.50" with FCE1 = group name, 1.5 = hours and 22.50 = cost. Thanks for looking at the problem

Answer (score 0):

If it is safe to assume that group name will never contain spaces you could use String.split() to get the data.

something like this:

```
String[] datas = barcode.split(" ");
String groupName = datas[0];
double hours = Double.valueOf(datas[1]);
double cost = Double.valueOf(datas[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks Sean I will try this out and see what happens :)